# mapping the metering metadata views

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, monitoring

I am trying to make sense of the billing and usage metadata tables in organization_usage schema.

I had assumed SNOWFLAKE.ORGANIZATION_USAGE.METERING_DAILY_HISTORY holds the summarized values of individual rows in SNOWFLAKE.organization_USAGE.WAREHOUSE_METERING_HISTORY.

Apparently it is not.

Can any one point out what can be the reason.

I tried the following two queries expecting the same output

select sum(credits_used) from SNOWFLAKE.organization_USAGE.WAREHOUSE_METERING_HISTORY
where date(start_time) =

select sum(credits_used) from SNOWFLAKE.ORGANIZATION_USAGE.METERING_DAILY_HISTORY
where usage_date =

but they are different. I tried on different dates and also tried filtering by service_type. Still they dont tally.

Answer (score 0):

One of the views is specific to warehouses and the other covers all credit usage. What the views contain is explained in the documentation - specifically look at the SERVICE_TYPE column in the METERING_DAILY_HISTORY View

**Update**

I had a look at one of my SF accounts and in most cases WAREHOUSE_METERING_HISTORY and METERING_DAILY_HISTORY were aligned - however there were a couple of days of discrepancies in the past month. I did some investigation and WMH only includes warehouse costs whereas MDH includes all costs. By querying METERING_HISTORY for the days where there were discrepancies, I could see that there were compute credits being consumed for SEARCH OPTIMIZATION; as these aren't associated to a warehouse they don't appear in the WMH view

Comment: AS I mentioned, I had filtered it by service_type = 'warehouse_metering'. still dont tally.

Comment: For METERING_DAILY_HISTORY  the definition of CREDITS_USED (which is what you are using in your query) is “Total of CREDITS_USED_COMPUTE plus CREDITS_USED_CLOUD_SERVICES.”. Even if you used CREDITS_USED_COMPUTE it probably wouldn’t match your warehouse credits as it is defined as “Number of credits used for warehouses and serverless compute resources”

Comment: the structure is same for metering_daily_history as well as warehouse_metering_history. there are three columns - credits_used, Credits_used_compute, Credits_used_cloud_services. the first column is a sum of the other two. I am only comparing like to like. You can try credits_used_compute and tell me if it tallies